# Inclusion of quadratic function in Big O notation

Tags: big-o

> We have seen that the Big O notation provides a strict upper bound for
>   f(n). This means that the function f(n) can do better but not worse
>   than the specified value.
>
> Examples of functions in O(n3) include: n2.9, n3, n3 + n, 540n3 + 10
>
> Examples of functions not in O(n3) include: n3.2, n2, n2 + n, 540n +
>   10, 2n
>
> This from the book @Data Structures Using C", Reema Thareja

So the question is - Why n^2 is not in n^3, as it's less and hence below the upper bound n^3? At the same time n^2.9 is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo or some other kind of mistake. All named functions are in O(n^3) except for n^3.2.

Example 2.1 from the same book even shows that 4n^2 is in O(n^3).